# What does この程度 mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

大丈夫だ、この程度……

My guess is - It's okay, I know my limits……

Context:

「いい加減寝たらどうだ？ カレル……。 一咋日からずっとなんだろう？ 体がもたんぞ。

「大丈夫だ、この程度……

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > 大丈夫だ、この程度……
>
> My guess is - It's okay, I know my limits……
>
> Context:
> 「いい加減寝たらどうだ？ カレル……。 一咋日からずっとなんだろう？ 体がもたんぞ。
> 「大丈夫だ、この程度……

Well, good guess, they are similar, but 'limit' would be 限界{げんかい}, and 程度｛ていど｝ is nothing more or less than '***degree***' or '***level***' or '***amount***' of something as any dictionary should say. He's saying something like "I'm all right with *this much of* thing" or "*This is not much* to me, or  *this amount of hardship is not much* to me.

It's synonym to この位｛くらい｝or これ位｛くらい｝. Mm... but we don't say <strike>これ程度</strike>.

大丈夫だよ、この程度（のこと）、これ位（のこと）、これしきのこと (might be old-fashioned or literary)、等々。